# find the set of common files between several directories?

Tags: shell

I'm looking to compare directories of Drupal themes. A drupal theme is a directory composed of several files, and I'm trying to figure out which ones are essential. For instance, they might all have a file called `template.php` or `page.tpl.php`.

How can I find the set of all common files for several directories? In my case, all the 'same' files (those of the same name) are going to be in the same level directory.

Comment: There are some answers in the 'Shell Puzzle' section of http://www.ukuug.org/newsletter/10.4/ (though they're shell-golf-ish).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List all names (not paths) of files common to all directories.

```
dirs=( "A dir" "B dir" "C dir" "D dir" )
find "${dirs[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*" -printf '%f\n' |
  sort | uniq -c | sed -n "s/^ *${#dirs[@]} //p"
```

Or call it as a script-file or function, with the directories as parameters.

```
find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*" -printf '%f\n' |
  sort | uniq -c | sed -n "s/^ *$# //p"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display a list of names sorted by the number of directories they appear in.

```
find */ |              # traverse all the template directories
sort -t / -k 2 |       # sort, ignoring the first field
tr '/' '\t' |          # turn / into tabs
uniq -f 1 -c |         # count duplicates, ignoring the first field
tr '\t' '/' |          # turn tabs back into /
sort -t / -s -k 1n     # sort by the number of occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) you can compare two directories, and see which files are present in one, and not in the other and vice versa. It can also show the differences between the common files.

Answer (score 0):

For 3 directories, one of them the current, and two 'a' and 'b', you can chain the test like this:

```
ls a/$(ls b/$(ls *.php) 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null
```

if the files have a common pattern (like .php) and don't contain whitespace in filenames.

Using `ls` in Scripts is always problematic and I normally discourage from using it, but if you have an overview about all the files in the directory where the search starts, and it doesn't contain whitespace, nor special characters like "*" or "?", "<" or "|", it should be save to use it.